# Smooth submanifold of $C^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

How can I
prove that a subset of $C^n$ given by the following equation:
$ Z^2_1+Z^2_2+ .... +Z^2_n = 1$
is a smooth submanifold of $C^n$, which is diffeomorphic to the tangent space of an $(n-1)$ dimensional sphere, $S^{n-1}$?
Am I to prove that the sphere is diffeomorphic to it's own tangent space?
Because I couldn't quite understand the problem itself.

Comment: No, the sphere is not diffeomorphic to its tangent space.

Comment: Tangent space, or tangent bundle?

Comment: No, the exercise is to prove that the hyperquadric $\sum Z_i^2=1$ in $\Bbb C^n$ is diffeomorphic to the tangent *bundle* of $S^{n-1}$. Note that the tangent bundle of $S^{n-1}$ is a real $2(n-1)$-dimensional manifold. The hyperquadric is a complex $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold, which makes it a real $2(n-1)$-dimensional manifold.